# Plotly R - interactive filter & discrete colour by group

Tags: r, plotly

I'm having some troubles with `plotly` in R. I am creating an rmarkdown, and am making use of the `updatemenus` & `transforms` feature to add a drop down. I've made some dummy data to highlight the problem that I have.

I want to be able to control the colours in a discrete way. I have 3 individuals in each group, and I want them to have the same set of colours when you change group. so colour of a = colour of d in this case; b=e, c=f.

In reality I have a lot more groups, so when I set this plot up, my colours within a group barely vary, and it looks unprofessional.

Sample code is below, any ideas how to do this would be great. Otherwise I'll have to try rewritting with ggplot and ggplotly which I find look less polished, and I try to use the plotly functions where I can.

```
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)
# make data. Assign first set a-c to group 1, d-f to group 2
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(individual = sample(letters[1:6], 100, replace = TRUE),
                 x = runif(100), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
groups <- c("g1", "g2")
df$group[match(df$individual, letters) <= 3] <- groups[1]
df$group[match(df$individual, letters) > 3] <- groups[2]
df$y <- df$x*(match(df$individual, letters))
df <- df[order(df$individual),]

# can see data is split ok
table(df$group, df$individual)

# build up interactive element, the filter to the two groups
button_list <- lapply(1:length(groups), function(x){
  list(method = "restyle",
       args = list("transforms[0].value", groups[x]),
       label = groups[x])
})
type_list <-  list(
  type = 'dropdown',
  active = 0,
  xanchor = 'center',
  yanchor = "top",
  pad = list('r'= 0, 't'= 10, 'b' = 10),
  x = 0.5,
  y = 1.27,
  buttons = button_list
)

# make plot, color based on the individual in the group
plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, mode = "lines+markers",
        color = ~ individual, 
        colors = brewer.pal(3, "Set1"),
        hoverinfo = "text", text = ~paste(individual),
        transforms = list(
          list(
            type = 'filter',
            target = ~group,
            operation = '=',
            value = df$group[1]
          ))
        ) %>%
          layout(updatemenus = list(
                   type_list
                 ))
```

Cheers

Comment: `colors = rep( brewer.pal(3, "Set1"), 2) ,` an option?

Comment: Thanks, that works well! You can add this as an answer if you like, and I'll accept it

Comment: @Wimpel, any ideas on how to get the legend to change based on the group drop down, e.g. a,b,c for g1, def for g2?

Comment: nope.. not very experienced in plotly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick and dirty: fill the colors with the 'permitted' colors

`colors = rep( brewer.pal(3, "Set1"), 2)`